# Openshift API query with Openshift/Client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools, client-go

Im trying to list all the build configs in openshift with help of openshift/client-go

```
import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"

    buildv1 "github.com/openshift/client-go/build/clientset/versioned/typed/build/v1"
)

func main() {
    err := start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func start() error {
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    // use the current context in kubeconfig
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    buildV1Client, err := buildv1.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    namespace := "testproject"
    // get all builds
    builds, err := buildV1Client.Builds(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("There are %d builds in project %s\n", len(builds.Items), namespace)
    // List names of all builds
    for i, build := range builds.Items {
        fmt.Printf("index %d: Name of the build: %s", i, build.Name)
    }
    return nil
}

func homeDir() string {
    if h := os.Getenv("HOME"); h != "" {
        return h
    }
    return os.Getenv("USERPROFILE") // windows
}
```

I have got all the dependencies via glide. glide.yaml `glide update -v`

```
package: .
import:
- package: github.com/openshift/client-go
  subpackages:
  - build/clientset/versioned/typed/build/v1
- package: k8s.io/apimachinery
  subpackages:
  - pkg/apis/meta/v1
- package: k8s.io/client-go
  subpackages:
  - tools/clientcmd
```

I see that all my packages are part of vendor. But I cant get the type changed to vendor config.

```
go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:39:44: cannot use config (type *"k8s.io/client-go/rest".Config) as type *"github.com/openshift/client-go/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/rest".Config in argument to "github.com/openshift/client-go/build/clientset/versioned/typed/build/v1".NewForConfig
./main.go:46:88: cannot use "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".ListOptions literal (type "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".ListOptions) as type "github.com/openshift/client-go/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".ListOptions in argument to buildV1Client.Builds(namespace).List
```

I have deleted the vendor directory in the current directory and made sure gopath have all the required dependencies as an alternative try, But that doesnt work.
I also tried to link ~/go/src/github.com/openshift/client-go/vendor/* vendor but that doesnt seem to work.

I also tried the solution [List Openshift objects via Go client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760596/list-openshift-objects-via-go-client-api). Which did not work.

Comment: @arghyasadhu  tried the same solution and it did not work.

Comment: it worked or not worked?

Comment: Sorry it did not work for me

Answer (score 5):

glide is a bit [outdated](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) as of this writing. Its last release was 07/10/2019.

Since version `1.11` Golang came up with its native package management called [go modules](https://golang.org/ref/mod#tmp_0) and that has become the more preferred way to manage dependencies. That's what manages your `vendor` directory and this is what `github.com/openshift/client-go` uses. I'm also assuming that you started from [this `main.go` file](https://github.com/openshift/client-go/blob/master/examples/build/main.go).

Since everything under `github.com/openshift/client-go` has the dependencies already managed. I recommend :

```sh
go get github.com/openshift/client-go
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/mygihubusername/myrepo
cp -R ../../openshift/client-go/* .
# put main.go here with your code or any of the subdirectories
# cd subdir  if you put the main.go file under a subdir.
go build -o buildclient . 
# clean up any files you don't need
# create github repo
git add *
git commit -m 'My first commit'
git push origin master
```

Works for me. ✌️